# Array as protected Object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, protected

I'm trying to build a JavaScript constructor which has an array as a property with read-only access:

```
var Word = function() {
  var _occurrences = [];
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    "occurrences": {
      get: function() {
        return _occurrences;
      }
    },
    "addOccurence": {
      value: function(occ) {
        _occurrences.push(occ);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

The array itself is a private variable with a get-er pointing to it.

```
var myWord = new Word();
myWord.addOccurrence(123);
var occ = myWord.occurrences;
```

All works fine.

```
myWord.occurrences = [];
```

Is blocked, as it should be. But surprisingly, this works:

```
myWord.occurrences.push(321);
```

Protecting a property keeps it from new assignments, but not from write access through Array methods - even though it is only accessed through a getter. That makes `Object.defineProperty()` rather pointless to me.

`Object.freeze()` / `Object.seal()` is not an option as I need write access for my `addOccurrences()` method.

Any ideas? Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript only provides you with references to objects (including arrays). When you `return _occurrences`, you return a reference to the array, so you can manipulate it.

If you want to prevent that, return a copy of the array instead.

```
return _occurrences.concat();
```

Comment: That was the one thing I didn't think about ... thanks a lot!

Comment: But should it be _occurrences.copy()? contat is there to concatinate arrays

Comment: @stefferd — Concatenating an array to nothing gives you a copy.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, but why not just use the copy function

Comment: Because `[].copy();`
*TypeError: `[].copy` is not a function*

Answer (score 1):

If you want the object private you should write it like this:

```
(function(window) {
  var _occurrences = [];

  function Word() { /*empty constructor*/ }

  Word.prototype.get = function() {
    return _occurrences;
  };
  Word.prototype.add = function(value) {
    _occurrences.push(value);
  };

  window.Word = Word
})(window);
```

This way the scope is only available inside the created instance of the object. The value of the _occurences in the instance can not be overriden.

A created an example of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fxxaB/2/

But if you want the array accessed outside of the array i would recommend the following solution add a function like the example below:

```
Word.prototype.instance = function() {
  return _occurences.copy();
}
```

This way the array is accesible but the values can still not be manipulated.

Comment: Yes, channelling access to the array through a custom-built getter function indeed protects the array. I would use this only as a fallback solution though, as I prefer to read access the array from outside with `obj.myArray` or `obj.myArray[index]` instead of `obj.myArray()`.